# load servlet on startup in magnolia cms

Tags: servlets, config, magnolia

I configure the setting of my servlet in /server/filters/servlets and I need my servlet to be loaded immediately after starting of the appliacation itself. So what kind of property should I add to my configuration in order to do that.

Comment: What exactly does "immediately" mean in this case? They're all started eventually without any further action required.

Comment: If I configure servlet I configure mapping for it as well and it doesn't start immediately after starting of the application. I know that "load-on-startup' can be added in the configuration of web.xml, but with magnolia at least in my case it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`ServletDispatchingFilter` is loading given servlet in its `init()` method and that one is in turned invoked when container initialises whole filter chain so it should be loaded out of the box w/o you having to do any changes since filters are always loaded on startup.